# What are some logistic of mounts can also fly and swim?

Tags: flight, mounts, swimming

So I have this dragon thingy named Kebera in my vampire-demon(?)-dragon world, that Zerk/'Gutsy' and Tincan 1000/TK-1000/TK, a human and small robot respectfully, ride upon.

Kebera can of coarse walk and run, pretty fast I should note, but also can fly given it is a dragony thing, and also swim pretty decently.

I am wondering what stuff I should take account for since it can also fly and swim. Like, would you ride it like a flying/swimming horse or is riding a flying(and swimming) steed totally different? How would you train it to fly and swim how you need it to? Would you need different riding gear? What safety rules would you need to follow? I especially want info on the flying part.

(Crude drawing of Gutsy, TK-1000, and Kebera below)

[image: Crude Drawing Of Kebera(1 of tongues out), Gutsy, and TK-1000]

Comment: Beep! Beep! Inconsistent technological level detected. Why would a society which has autonomous robots even consider using animal-powered cavalry? Ditch the cantankerous, smelly, inefficient, high-maintenance horses and use proper self-propelled vehicles. Ah, you will say, but this is artistic license, and you want the army to have autonomous robots and camel-riding cavalry; in which case, what is the question about? If the rule of cool rules, the rule of cool rules. It makes no sense to ask about the rational practicalities of a completely irrational army.

Comment: This world is an apocalypse one. A massive vampiric, possibly demonic, dragon and her spawn have trapped humanity in dreamworlds in order to farm them for blood to feed her. I think Kebera is one of her 'defect' spawn. BTW IDK if this work technically takes place on Earth or just an Earthlike world, that said, humanity was at most slightly more advanced then us now. Regardless, the state of the world is pretty much medieval to 3rd worldish villages scattered about so not much industrially. There are still advanced pieces of tech, just not many for aformentioned reasons. That make sense? @AlexP

Comment: Still not sure what this question is about. “Take into account” that it flies and swims? What does that mean? The riders need oxygen tanks? Warm coats and wet suits?

Comment: I want to know what would be needed to ride a flying and swimming mount, and how it differs from a landbased mount, especially the flight part. So maybe they do need that stuff, idk. @candied_orange

Comment: *"Have trapped humanity in dreamworlds":* The one consistent thing about dreamworlds is that they are not rational. There are no practical designs for riding gear. There are no safety rules. There is definitely no consideration of logistics. It's all a dream.

Comment: Ok, let me clarify, Kebera and crew are in base reality/real life/waking world, not the dream world. Gutsy WAS in a dreamworld, but he somehow escaped a while back, unless I plan on changing his backstory. @AlexP

Comment: As a general rule, if you can fly, there is no reason to Swim. Think of a Duck - they will happily paddle about on a lake or pond, but as soon as they need to travel any significant distance (like more than 10 metres) they will up and fly. If the weather is bad enough that flying isn't a good idea, then chances are that staying on the Water isn't going to be too much fun either.

Comment: @TheDemonLord there are several flying animals that are also good swimmers, they are birds that dive for fish like cormorants.

Comment: @john - sure, but Cormorants dive *for food* - not to travel. Whilst thinking about this - the only scenario that would make any real sense would be a cave system where it's got a large river, but not enough height to fly in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are ducks. Not dragons, ducks:

[image]

Most importantly, ducks are not very good on the Earth. To swim, to fly and to walk, these are very different things and you can not be very good in all of them.

1. *They must have some weak spot, at least one of them they should do badly.* For example, ducks can walk, but they are not very good in it.
2. *Their effectivity lies not in that they would be good swimmers, good fliers or good walkers, their effectivity lies in that they can do all of them.*

Very likely, these dragons (ducks) are nowhere on the Earth as horses or oxes. For example, they need much more eat and they become much earlier bored. But no ox can fly, and they can, although nowhere to the eagles (Pegasi, if you like more).